# xmlns required for bean component of spring-servlet.xml for spring security application

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

How to determine what xmlns are required for beans component of my spring-servlet.xml(spring configuration file) for spring security application?

Is this is the correct code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">

...

</beans>
```

Comment: We can't tell you that without seeing what's in the file.

Comment: @skaffman I am just asking for the essential name space for the spring security application.

Comment: So read the Spring Security documentation, it's right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer in the spring framework reference and that is mention below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">
...
</beans>
```

In general it should be like this. for reference [Spring Security 3.0 Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.pdf)